# How to set viewbag value to input datetime type time

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have :

```
<input class="datefield" value="@ViewBag.SelectedFromHour" id="TimeFrom" name="TimeFrom" type="time">
```

My `@ViewBag.SelectedFromHour` value is `5:00`. But it does not display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value needs to be `05:00` (for 5 AM) or `17:00` (for 5 PM).

However, I strongly recommend you bind to you model by setting the value of `TimeFrom` and using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeFrom, new { @type = "time" })` (you property should be typeof `TimeSpan`)

Note also `type="time"` is not fully supported in all browsers.